# what is a unicode code point (U+)?

Tags: unicode

https://unicode-table.com/en/

the unicode there does not have a U+ in front

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

the unicode there does have a U+ in front

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point

I don't understand the Wikipedia explanation.

It seems all that's being done is adding a U+ to a perfectly valid Hex number. Why??

Comment: Why? How would you otherwise differentiate whether it is a number or a Unicode character representation in question. You really don't seem to have thought this over.

Comment: Unicode code points are just numbers.  `U+<hexdigits>` is just a convention to indicate a code point; it isn't a requirement, but makes the number you are talking about obvious if you understand the convention.

Comment: You could say that a price is just putting `$` in front of a perfectly valid decimal, or that a phone number is just putting hyphens in a perfectly valid integer between 2×10^10 and 2×10^11 (for US numbers), like 1-555-867-5309. You could write a phone number as 15,558,675,309; it would be the same number and you’d dial it the same way. You don’t do that, though, because it looks like you have 15 billion of something now.

Comment: thank you guys for pointing out that it's a signifying convention. I am just revising for exam. I can't believe people downvoted the question. There wasn't another one like it on Google as far as I could find

Comment: Upvoted. I couldn't find a proper explanation in Google as well. Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a convention to denote that the code point should be interpreted as Unicode.

For example, you might see `2e2e`, but without some context, you don't know what it signifies. The `U+` provides that context, making it clear that it represents "⸮"

Comment: thank you for very reasonable and clear explanation!